# JQuery replaceWith in Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, replacewith

I'm having some trouble replacing a button with another tag using replaceWith. My code:

```
<button name="button" type="button" class="join-button" 
        data-player="1">Join Game!</button>
buttonToText = (element) ->
  console.log(element)
  element.replaceWith( "<h1>hi</h1>" )

$ ->
  $(".join-button").on click:  ->
    buttonToText(this)
```

When the button is clicked, console.log appears to return the right value: the html of the button and the class is HTMLButtonElement. However, I'm getting `Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is Not a Function`
on the replaceWith line. Any ideas why the error is happening? This is all running off of Rails 4.2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also, replaceWith doesn't appear to be in the list of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` for the element, so I guess I can't use replaceWith here?

Comment: `this` in your callback would be a DOM node, right? But [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is a *jQuery* function, not a standard DOM node function. Maybe `$(element)` would be more useful.

Comment: RIght you are! `$(this)` instead of `this` or `$(element)` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`this` needs to be `$(this)` or `element` needs to be `$(element)`